# How to manually trigger click for Dropzone (open select file dialog)

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js, dropzone

Dropzone only works on the element itself i have an SPAN tag inside my button, and when i click on the text it won't trigger click on parent element which dropzone is attached to. i tried the following but it doesn't work!

```
$('.dropzone').click();
```

and also this

```
$('.dropzone').trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

by default dropzone only works on on element it self, and if you try to run trigger manually it wont work. the best way i could find after searching A LOT was this:

```
myDropzone.hiddenFileInput.click()
```

to find dropzone instant there are several ways:

1- by jquery: `var myDropZone =  $('.dropzone').get(0).dropzone;` or `var myDropZone = $("div#dropmehere").dropzone({...});` if you are using id to find your element

2- by Dropzone class itself: `var myDropzone = Dropzone.forElement("div#dropmehere");`

now you can

Comment: Thank you. It is also helpful to know that you don't need jquery to access any dropzone element. You can simply get the element like this too:
`var myDropZone =  document.getElementById("dropzone-id").dropzone`, although jquery works too

Comment: For this to work you must pass `clickable: true` or pass an element. Otherwise, the Dropzone has no `hiddenFileInput`.

Comment: Seems to be broken on firefox v.101 <input> picker was blocked due to lack of user activation.

Comment: @Daphoque did you fix it?

Comment: @Pezhvak it seems more related to a firefox issue, the snapped version of firefox v101 on ubuntu 22.04 blocked the action ; but it works with the firefox v01 binaries downloaded on mozilla website.

Answer (score 3):

While using vue dropzone you can simply open file dialog using below line.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("dropzone")[0].click();
```

Answer (score 2):

Quite late to the party here, but if you're looking for a solution for vue2-dropzone, (the vue wrapper for Dropzone.js), you can give the dropzone a reference  (e.g `<vue-dropzone ref=dropzone />`), then call `$refs.dropzone.$el.click()` to trigger the file upload dialog.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me `$('#dropzone_dropzone').get(0).dropzone.hiddenFileInput.click();`

where `#dropzone_dropzone` is the name of my DIV

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [solution](https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-dropzone-wrapper/issues/122) , it works fine. if your're using Angular you can proceed as follows

```
  @ViewChild(DropzoneDirective) dropzoneRef: DropzoneDirective;
```

in your method

```
this.dropzoneRef.dropzone().clickableElements[0].click();
```

Answer (score 0):

In version 5.7.2, all of the the following worked for me:

```
$("#dropzone")[0].click()
$("#dropzone").get(0).click()
document.getElementById("dropzone").click();
```